# Content ID for mail parts

Tags: java, email, outlook, jakarta-mail, thunderbird

What is the importance of Content ID in mail? Is there any difference in the way this value is set across the most popular mail clients say Thunderbird, Microsoft Outlook and so...
What are things a developer should have in mind while providing a service that is related to reading mails sent from different clients to provide cross client compatibility, specifically with Content ID?

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to keep in mind is that the Content-ID header for a body part is optional.  It's mostly only needed for multipart/related parts.

You should read RFC 2045, which defines the Content-ID header.

What were you planning to use the Content ID for?

Comment: I was using Content ID to differentiate between inline images and attachments. The content ID will be null for an attachment, specifically for mails that are sent from Thunderbird, but for inline images the content ID won't be null. Is there any difference in this aspect between mailing clients i.e Thunderbird and outlook.

Comment: There's no guarantee that the Content-ID will be null for attachments.  It might be true for some popular mailers so as long as you recognize that it's just a heuristic that might be fine.